# MQL4 Time function miscalculation

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

I have the following function where tries to calculate the time between the last closed trade and the current time. if the time difference is <> that a certain number of bars it gives a different result.

that being said, during the backtest at some point the bar calculation begins to fail and i do not find the error. Any thoughts?

```
 int LastOrderTicket()
  {
   datetime TicketTime = 0;
   int LastOT;

   datetime
   Timeorder = LastOrderTime(),
   Timeahora = TimeCurrent(),
   Times = Timeahora - Timeorder;

   int
   m         = TimeMinute(Times),
   h         = TimeHour(Times),
   d         = TimeDay(Times),

   bars      = (((d - 1) * 24 * 60) + (h * 60) + m) / 240;

   

   for(int ix = 0; ix < OrdersHistoryTotal(); ix++)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(ix, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY)
         && OrderMagicNumber() == MagicNumber
         && OrderSymbol() == Symbol())
        {
           if(bars > barsback)
           {
            LastOT = -1;
           } 
       else
          { 
            if(bars  < barsback)
             {
            LastOT = OrderType();        //For testing
             }
           
        }
       } 

      else
         Print("OrderSelect returned the error of ",GetLastError());
     }

       Print("TicketN ",LastOT);
       Print("bars ",bars);
       Print("Timeorder=",TimeToStr(Timeorder, TIME_MINUTES|TIME_SECONDS|TIME_DATE));
       Print("Timeahora=",TimeToStr(Timeahora, TIME_MINUTES|TIME_SECONDS|TIME_DATE));
       Print("Times=",TimeToStr(Times, TIME_MINUTES|TIME_SECONDS|TIME_DATE));
       Print("m ",m);
       Print("h ",h);
       Print("d ",d);

   return(LastOT); // Buy==0, Sell==1, Others==2 through 5
  }
```

Here where i find the error:

```
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.06 23:59:59  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: bars 182
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.06 23:59:59  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: Timeorder=2021.03.09 12:00:00
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.06 23:59:59  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: Timeahora=2021.08.06 23:59:59
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.06 23:59:59  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: Times=1970.05.31 11:59:59
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.06 23:59:59  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: m 59
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.06 23:59:59  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: h 11
**0 18:02:11.243    2021.08.06 23:59:59  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: d 31**
```

```
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.08 23:05:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: bars 8
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.08 23:05:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: Timeorder=2021.03.09 12:00:00
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.08 23:05:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: Timeahora=2021.08.08 23:05:00
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.08 23:05:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: Times=1970.06.02 11:05:00
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.08 23:05:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: m 5
0   18:02:11.243    2021.08.08 23:05:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: h 11
**0 18:02:11.243    2021.08.08 23:05:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4: d 2**
```

the function time keep summing up but the day value not...

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i've used *ibarshif* and it worked.

thank you anyway.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
datetime lastTime = TimeCurrent()-OrderOpenTime();
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. –

Comment: Thank you Yasin, but the problem persists. Just run again and reaching the same stage the bars just drop down to 8.

Comment: ibarshif try it